# Origin of "weird" baudrates for serial communication

Tags: serial-port

Why are there baudrates like 115.200 Baud? There has to be some origin for this. One answer might be the crystal frequencies like 19.6608 Mhz or 1.8432 Mhz, which you can use to divide by an integer and get the wanted baudrates. But this looks even stranger to me.

And further more:
Take the baudrate 115200 and divide it by 2, you get 57600 bps. Dividing further by 2 you get 28800 bps, 14400 bps, ... These are common used baudrates, but the most common baudrate of 9600 bps you have to divide 115200 baud by 3 and you get 38400 bps. Dividing further by 2 you get 19200 bps, 9600 bps, 4800 bps, ...

What's the historical reason for this?

Comment: I remember 110 and 300 like it was yesterday.

Comment: I typed most of my dissertation over a 300 baud dial-in line to our computer science center. When I finally got my hands on a 1200-baud modem, I thought I was in heaven.

Comment: While this is an interesting question that I'd like to know the answer to, it is probably [off-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  It may be better placed on [SU](http://superuser.com/) or [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this origin can be traced back to the original hardware design of the IBM PC.  For reference that machine used a single core 4.77 MHz CPU, so modern PCs are about 1000x faster (even more if you consider the data path is now 64 bits wide, not 8)

IBM originally supported a maximum of 9600 baud and no faster.   Their engineers selected the frequency 115200 because it was easy to divide by 12 to derive 9600 baud.

And even as computers became faster, hardware makers kept this frequency for compatibility with existing software.

New software could be backwards compatible and also allowed folks to also select faster baud rates above 9600 to 115200.

In some ways 115200 is like the key combination Ctrl-Alt-Del.  It is something that IBM chose, and then it became a standard.